# Standard practices for organizing models in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am building an application that has a "Web Planner" where the user goes between a number of pages in order to complete a large process. Each page they provide more information than the last and some pages are dependent on other pages to get the correct data.

For instance lets take an example like:

`Customer Info -> Accounts -> Settings -> Final Review`

This is a 4 page "Web Planner" that a user must complete before placing an order on our site.  Right now I have a `RootController` that is used for functions and data that is shared across all pages, then I have other controllers for each of the other pages.

It makes sense that the `Final Review` page would contains pieces of information from all of the previous pages and would result in a "Summary" of the web planner.  We allow our users to "Save" their order at any given step and then return later on. Therefore they will not ALWAYS go in the above order to get to `Final Review`.

So my question is, what is the best way to organize and structure this application so that even if the user opens their browser and goes directly to `Final Review` then they will receive all the correct information.

It would seem simple enough to just place all API calls on the `RootController` and then no matter what page they come to, we retrieve all of the data all at once. The only problem with that is depending on where they are in the Web Planner when they hit "Save" only parts of the information will be available.

Is there a standard way to shared information across multiple pages in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using AngularJS services to share the information between each of the pages in the process. Services are commonly used for the purpose of data sharing between controllers.

**An Example Service**

For your example, you might want to create something like a `WebPlanner` service. This would keep track of all the data from each step in the process. Below is quite a basic example, so you will want to expand it using the model from your `RootController`.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('WebPlanner', function() {
    return {
        customerInfo: {
            name: ''
        },
        accounts {
            accountId: ''
        },
        settings {
            exampleSetting: false
        },
        finalReview {
            userHasConfirmed: false
        }
    }
})
```

**Example Controllers**

You can then access this service from the controllers at each step of the process. This will allow each of your controllers to both read and write to the data stored in the service.

Writing:

```
function CustomerInfoCtrl($scope, WebPlanner){
    WebPlanner['customerInfo']['name'] = $scope.name;
}
```

Reading:

```
function FinalReviewCtrl($scope, WebPlanner){
    $scope.userHasConfirmed = WebPlanner['finalReview']['userHasConfirmed'];
}
```

You can read more about services at:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: I am aware of AngularJS services and use them for other reasons, but I am not sure how I could structure a service that would do something like this. Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Sure. Just to check, does each step in the process have its own controller?

Comment: Yes, like I said there is a `RootController` that is instantiated no matter what page you visit and then there is also a Controller for each page

Comment: @MattHintzke - Thanks. I've updated the answer with more detail and some examples. Let me know if there's anything I could add to improve the answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: I feel like this is basically no different than what I am already doing by placing the model on the RootController. There is still no logic to determine what API calls are made in order to get the correct information for a view.  This may be a case where I just have to do what I think is best

Comment: Sorry @MattHintzke but I'm a little confused as to what you are looking for. You asked if there was a standard way to share data across multiple pages, and the standard way is through AngularJS services. What sort of extra logic would you like the solution to include?

Comment: Sorry but I think my case is just one that is not generally defined.. It is a mix of sharing data across pages and enforcing logic to get the correct set of API requests depending on the page. I will probably just have to implement my own algo to get it to work properly. Thank you for trying though